# Checkout Subscribe not working in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I installed the extension **Checkout Subscribe** and it is working fine for me. But there is a small problem. I already installed the Fontis extension of Recaptcha. It was working fine. But after installing this extension the Recaptcha disappear. I tried to disable the recaptcha for registration page. But no luck. Hope you can help. I am using Magento 1.7